# extract object values and insert into string at exact positions

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have the follow JSON description of column titles that I would like to extract and place in the correct 'position' in an array of strings

```
header = {
          "columns": {
             "col1": {
               "label": [ "Col1Row1", "Col1Row2" ],
               "width": 12,
               "position" : 10
            },
             "col2": {
               "label": ["Col2Row1", "Col2Row2", "Col2Row3"],
               "width": 9,
               "position" : 23
            }
        }
```

with an array looking like so where Col1 is in the 10 position and Col2 is in the 23 position:

```
header[0] = '          Col1Row1     Col2Row1        '
header[1] = '          Col1Row2     Col2Row2        '
header[2] = '                       Col2Row3        '
```

I've tried a number of times, but generated incredibly verbose code by using .slice, .substr, .concat, etc.  I can't come up with a concise way to transform the contents.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What is `width` value used for? Also, *"Am I missing something obvious"* ... it's hard to tell without seeing any code - what's missing.

Comment: Please post the code that you came up with so that we can help you improve it.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if  `columns` was an array of column objects sorted by their `position`

Comment: Also, is this a possible state `"label": ["Col4Row1", "Col4Row2", "", "Col4Row4"],` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the cols one-by-one, adding spaces to each string until they have enough characters to match the `position` (you can achieve this concisely with by calling `padEnd` with a space), then add the label:

```js
const header = {
  "columns": {
     "col1": {
       "label": [ "Col1Row1", "Col1Row2" ],
       "width": 12,
       "position" : 10
    },
     "col2": {
       "label": ["Col2Row1", "Col2Row2", "Col2Row3"],
       "width": 9,
       "position" : 23
    }
  }
};
const arr = [];
for (const { label, position } of Object.values(header.columns)) {
  label.forEach((labelStr, i) => {
    arr[i] = (arr[i] || '').padEnd(position, ' ') + labelStr;
  });
}
console.log(arr);
```

Though they are in your example, if the columns aren't ordered, you'll have to sort them first:

```js
const header = {
  "columns": {
     "col1": {
       "label": [ "Col1Row1", "Col1Row2" ],
       "width": 12,
       "position" : 10
    },
     "col2": {
       "label": ["Col2Row1", "Col2Row2", "Col2Row3"],
       "width": 9,
       "position" : 23
    }
  }
};
const arr = [];
for (const { label, position } of Object.values(header.columns).sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position)) {
  label.forEach((labelStr, i) => {
    arr[i] = (arr[i] || '').padEnd(position, ' ') + labelStr;
  });
}
console.log(arr);
```

Though this isn't an issue with your example, if any of the labels are too large to fit in a column, slice off the end of the last `arr[i]`:

```js
const header = {
  "columns": {
     "col1": {
       "label": [ "Col1Row1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Col1Row2" ],
       "width": 12,
       "position" : 10
    },
     "col2": {
       "label": ["Col2Row1", "Col2Row2", "Col2Row3"],
       "width": 9,
       "position" : 23
    }
  }
};
const arr = [];
for (const { label, position } of Object.values(header.columns).sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position)) {
  label.forEach((labelStr, i) => {
    arr[i] = (arr[i] || '').slice(0, position - 1).padEnd(position, ' ') + labelStr;
  });
}
console.log(arr);
```

(that's if you want the labels to be if you want one space between the labels in that situation. If you want to adjust the spacing, change the `position - 1` parameter to `.slice`)

Comment: You might want to `.sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position)` the columns array, and `.slice(0, width)` the `labelStr`ings to avoid issues with unordered columns and oversize labels.